# Use MongoDB Stitch as backend for Xamarin Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, xamarin, backend

Is their any way to use mongodb stitch as backend for Xamarin Application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there are JavaScript, iOS (Swift), and Android (Java) SDKs to connect to Stitch. We've also open sourced our SDKs [here](https://github.com/mongodb?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Stitch&type=&language=), so there is the opportunity to build on what we've done as well. While there isn't a C# SDK for working with Xamarin at the moment, we have plans to investigate this later and are happy to help anyone interested in contributing.